# What is the purpose of the instrumentation API in Ruby/Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Based on: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Notifications.html

It says:

> Notifications provides an instrumentation API for Ruby. To instrument an action in Ruby you just need to do:

What exactly is an instrumentation API and what does it do?

### Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

There is a very nice railscast on this topic:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/249-notifications-in-rails-3

Comment: To paraphrase the talk: `Notifications` allows any event in Rails to be logged while maintaining separation between the code that triggers the event and the code that wants to log it (by using a publish/subscribe pattern). This is especially useful for recording performance data (ex. how long a request takes).

Comment: +0 for not summarizing the talk.

Comment: -1 Please provide a detailed/summarised answer whatever you've understood from the reference you are providing for future reference, instead of just posting the URL.

Answer (score 0):

The instrumentation API in ActiveSupport serves a dual purpose.

1. To implement the publish-subscribe (observer) pattern, allowing you to subscribe and listen to various events that occur within your application or the Rails framework.
2. To benchmark a piece of code, to measure how long it took to execute some action.

Check out these resources for some concrete examples:

- [Understanding the Instrumentation API in Rails](https://www.akshaykhot.com/rails-instrumentation-api/)
- [Rails documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_instrumentation.html)